# Implementing OAuth2 with Rauth for vk.com

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, vk, rauth

I'm trying to implement Oauth2 authorization using Rauth for vk.com provider and I have the following issue:

As far as I know there is no way to obtain users email address through vk.com api call, but it sends email address with access_token in json format.

My problem is: I do not know how to obtain it from Rauth's "session" object, there is an access_token field but no way to get an email address.

Here is the code:

```
def callback(self):
    def decode_json(payload):
        return json.loads(payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if 'code' not in request.args:
        return None, None, None
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
        data={'code': request.args['code'],
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()},
        decoder=decode_json
    )
    me = oauth_session.get("some call to vk.api").json()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have `email` rights in the scope?

Comment: Yes, I have scope='email' and vk returns email with access token in json if I try it manually through browser, but I just can not extract it from Rauth's session object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain. Actually, `email` is returned by Vkontakte along with access token in case it is provided.

You don't need to use `oauth_session.get` since it does make a new request, but it is already done, when you got access token. Try to get an object property with `oauth_session.email`.

P.S. you can find email using `get_raw_access_token`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I have mentioned in my question there is no such property in oauth_session object as 'email', there is 'access_token', Rauth extracts it from vkontakte response but not email

Comment: Sounds strange. But it is returned exactly with access_token. Ok, good luck. I'd check `get_raw_access_token` if email exists in raw return. This is up to you then.

Comment: You are correct Ivan `get_raw_access_token`  helps, there is `.json` method which returns raw json sent by vkontakte containing email address. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I knew the truth was somewhere before making a new request)

Comment: You can check the answer as helpful. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I guess I don't have enough reputation for my vote to display. I marked answer as accepted but may be it makes sense to mention `get_raw_access_token` there.

Comment: OK, I've just added. But nevertheless it exists here.